# Raw mouse input 14.04

Tags: mouse

How can I enable raw mouse input in 14.04. That is

No modifications on acceleration.
No change regarding movement speed. Therefore the DPI/CPI of the mouse should correspond to the amount of pixels the cursor will move when the mouse is moved one inch.

This is the output of xinput:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G400s Optical Gaming Mouse       id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 046a:010d                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 046a:010d                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Which mouse are you asking about? Logitech or the other one?

Comment: Logitech. I don't know what the other entry is, cause I actually never used a different one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable mouse acceleration this way.

Create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-disable-mouse-accel.conf` with this content

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
EndSection
```

and restart session.

Comment: What do i write in "My Mouse" ?

Comment: Leave it as it is.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I created the file and added the content that you provided. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 . I have a wireless mouse that is lised in xinput as "MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control id=20 [slave  keyboard (3)]"

Comment: You can always ask a question.